# Gcc, using no_caller_saved_registers attribute

Tags: c++, c, gcc, attributes

I am trying to compile some C functions, using `gcc` not to run over any registers. I am working on `x86_64`.
I am trying to use `no_caller_saved_registers`, but all I get is this:

> warning: ‘no_caller_saved_registers’ attribute directive ignored [-Wattributes]
>
> void foo() **attribute**((no_caller_saved_registers));

My temporary solution was to write inline assembly prologue and epilogue to save and restore all registers, but I REALLY prefer to make the attribute work.

Did anyone have this problem?

Comment: Can you explain what you ACTUALLY are trying to do? I'm reasonably sure you can't force gcc to NOT use registers in a function - certainly not for anything complex, since most instructions in x86 do require one operand to be a register at the very least.

Comment: I am instrumenting assembly code, to call these functions. I am OK with them using any registers, as long as they would restore them.

Comment: I found this compilation flag, that has the affect I want, but on the entire file: -fcall-saved-reg. It doesn't work correctly on some registers (rax, rdx)

Comment: Why dont you just save the registers you need? I still dont know exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MegaStupidMonkeys To make these functions code platform-independent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No_caller_saved_registers has only been implemented [in June 2016](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=237073) so it's not available in any official GCC release atm.

Comment: Update: this attribute is supported for gcc 7.2. Have to add this compilation flag:
gcc-7 main.c -mgeneral-regs-only

Answer (score 0):

I need a function that doesn't clobber ANY registers, because it is a kind of a page fault handler.
Thanks to the previous answer here, we know that this attribute will be supported in future gcc releases, but is not mainstream yet.

Without this attribute, my function, that I use as some sort of page fault handler that must not clobber any registers values looks like this:

```
#define PREFIX_SIZE (14l)
__asm__ volatile ("in: \n\t"
                  "pushf\n\t"
                  "push   %rbp\n\t"
                  "mov    %rsp,%rbp\n\t"
                  "push   %rdi\n\t"
                  "push   %rsi\n\t"
                  "push   %rdx\n\t"
                  "push   %rcx\n\t"
                  "push   %r8 \n\t"
                  "push   %r9 \n\t"
                  "push   %rax\n\t"
                  );

void page_fault_handler() {
    /*
     * some code here
     */
    __asm__ volatile ("jmp reg_out\n\t");
}

__asm__ volatile ("reg_out: \n\t"
                  "leave\n\t"   // what the original code was doing
                  "pop    %rax\n\t"
                  "pop    %r9 \n\t"
                  "pop    %r8 \n\t"
                  "pop    %rcx\n\t"
                  "pop    %rdx\n\t"
                  "pop    %rsi\n\t"
                  "pop    %rdi\n\t"
                  "leave\n\t"   // my leave
                  "popf\n\t"
                  "ret\n\t");
```

It is obviously annoying, because I have to call this address:

```
(void*)((ulong)page_fault_handler - PREFIX_SIZE)
```

instead of

```
(void*)page_fault_handler
```

It also causes problems when compiled with the -O2 optimization flag, because it reorders the labels.

If you note, I don't save rbx manually here, because I compiled this code with:

```
gcc -fcall-saved-rbx
```

This compilation flag causes the compiler to save and restore rbx in the beginning and end of functions.
So why I don't just do it for all registers?
Because it causes an internal compiler error for rax: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79407